# TyperError Django while using urls.py

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-urls

I'm beginner and I'm using Django 1.8.3 and Python 2.7.3.
I'm trying to run server and get the following error:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  108.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  74.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  647.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  522.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  366.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  402.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  396.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/bzi/bzi/urls.py" in <module>
  24.     url(r'^domains/', include('mailserver.urls')),
File "/home/stas/mercurial/internet.django/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/mercurial/internet.django/bzi/mailserver/urls.py" in <module>
  5.     url(r'^$', views.domains, name='domains'),

Exception Type: TypeError at /domains
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My project file urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^domains/', include('mailserver.urls')),
]
```

My app mailserver file urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns[
    url(r'^$', views.domains),
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `patterns` name:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.domains),
]
```

Comment: Would  be interested to know why someone downvoted this. `patterns()` was [deprecated in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns), so this is the correct answer.

Comment: Anyway this syntax is more elegant.

Comment: And more correct. You shouldn't use deprecated code in new projects.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in *urls.py*, you should write:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.domains),
]
```

Right now you are using square brackets "[]" after `patterns` - that is signal for python interpreter to call `patterns.__getitem__()` method, which is absent. That's why you get an error.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really works. I was confused and i didn't noticed, that I'm calling the "patterns" as a list.